# Insert word before last word in a string

Tags: asp.net, string, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to insert the word "and" before the last word in a string. This is my code so far:

```
    string skillset = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in SkillSet.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            skillset += item.Text + ", ";
        } 
    }
    skillset = skillset.Substring(0, skillset.Length - 2);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to put "and" in fron of the last word you can use to split your string into an array of strings, change the last word and join the string back together. It would look something like this

```
string[] skills = skillset.Split(new char[] { ',' });
skills[skills.Length-1] = "and " + skills[skills.Length-1];
skillset = string.Join(",", skills);
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position.

**Example**

```
string str = "We are loudly";
string mynewvalue = "talking";
str.Insert(str.Length - 1, mynewvalue);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
int myStringLength  = myString.length;

string myString = inputString.Substring(0, myStringLength);

int index = myString.LastIndexOf(' ');


string outputString = myString.Insert(index , " and ");
```

Example : http://www.dotnetperls.com/insert